# Custom Url Mapping Grails with Usernames

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have a problem with Url's Mapping in Grails.

I have an application with users and I shows their profiles with this url:

`/user/myProfile/2     (2 is the user's id)`

but I want that the url for show the user's profile is:

`/user/angelo087       (angelo087 is the username of the a user with id=2)`

I use the plugin "spring-security-core2.0-RC2" for the users.

I've tried it but I don't know how is this. The problem is that I don't know how to get the id of the user in UrlMappings.groovy for make the url.

Any help? =(

[EDIT: SOLUTION]

Finally, I knew how put the username in the url:

In `UrlMapping.groovy` I wrote:

```
"/user/$username" {
      controller="user"
      action = "myProfile"
}
```

After, in the `UserController.groovy` I wrote:

```
def myProfile() {
    def username = params.username
    def usuario = User.findByUsername(username.toString())
    [personaInstance: usuario.persona, usuarioInstance: usuario]
}
```

The problem was that I didn't know that in the URL you can put other variables of the array `params`.

Comment: Next time, you should post your solution as another answer - yes you are allowed to do that. BTW your included solution is pretty much the same as the answer I gave below (with very minor differences). On SO if an answer is provided that is (mostly) correct you should mark it with a tick. Yo may have come up with the answer yourself but it doesn't stop an answer from being correct, so you should mark it as such anyway. Plus my answer was there for over 10 hours before you posted your edit/solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a urlMapping something like:

```
"/user/$id"(controller:"user", action:"myProfile")
```

Then in your controller:

```
def user
if (id.isNumber()) {
    user = User.get(id)
} else {
    user = User.findByUsername(id)
}
```

This is a bit of a guess as you haven't included either your urlMapping or controller code.

Also, taking this route means it can be hit and miss calling other methods in that controller as the `id` and method names are indistinguishable. You can get around this by defining your other methods in urlMappings.groovy above the entry above. Its often easier to simply include the action name in the URL path.

Comment: I knew finally how was. I wanted that the username was in the URL and I didn't know that you could put other variables and after I get them in the controller. I've writen the solution in the question. Thanks a lot.